# Ember-data.js 500 status code

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way to handle 500 status error, when creating a new model e.g

```
var model = this.store.createRecord('user');
model.save().then(function() {

}, function(error) {
// this callback will not be executed if 500 status response
});
```

However, I can catch it using `becameError` event on model, but in this case an error object will not be available.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason why a 500 wouldn't make it back to the reject hook, maybe I'll need to create a quick mock to see it.  Does it hit neither hook?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am encountering the same problem.  I've also tried using catch like this:

```javascript
var model = this.store.createRecord('user');
model.save().then(function() {

}).catch(function(error) {
// this callback will not be executed if 500 status response
});
```

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was overriding "createMethod" in the adapter and I was catching errors there which didn't allow them to propagate to the controller's catch.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a 500 makes it back to the reject route

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/159/edit

Comment: kingpin2k, thanks for answer! But I think that I deal with some rare case) I'll try to reproduce it in the jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

You can override DS.Model save and assign values from the error hash to your models

```
App.Model = DS.Model.extend({
  save: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return this._super().then(function(obj) {
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
        return resolve(obj);
      });
    }, function(error) {
      //Do something with error here
      _this.set('error_status', error.status)
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        return reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Note. becameError event called before error function in save method, so 'error_status' isn't set when becameError called.

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = this.store.createRecord('user');
model.save().catch(function(error) {
  error.status; // status code
});
```